# HTML5 Canvas Colour Text

Tags: string, html, colors, canvas

How do I add colour to my text in canvas. When I tried fillStyle the text just stayed black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you indeed have to set fillStyle and then call fill();

```
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle= 'blue';
  ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Thanks, i found out after I posted the question. Here is the finished product of my question: http://nebkat.com/projects/alphaworks/